# How to display counts using the periodic table with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, chemistry

I have a list of elemental compositions and I'd like to display a count for the number of times an element is included in a composition mapped onto the periodic table (e.g.  `CH4` would increase the count on `H` and `C` by one).

How can I do this with `ggplot`?  Is there a map I can use?

Comment: I found this page to be very helpful: http://chepec.se/2014/11/16/element-data.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a bit of searching I found information about the periodic table in [this example code project](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Control/Draw-table-shape-vc-example-periodic.htm). They had an Access Database with element information. I've exported it to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/c1183c911bc5398105d4). You can import the data using the `httr` library with

```
library(httr)
dd <- read.table(text=content(GET("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MrFlick/c1183c911bc5398105d4/raw/715868fba2d0d17a61a8081de17c468bbc525ab1/elements.txt")), sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

(You should probably create your own local version for easier loading in the future.)

Then your other challenge is decomposing something like "CH4" into the raw element counts. I've created this helper function which I think does what you need.

```
decompose <- function(x) {
    m <- gregexpr("([A-Z][a-z]?)(\\d*)", x, perl=T)
    dx <- Map(function(x, y) {
        ElementSymbol <- gsub("\\d","", x)
        cnt <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D","", x))
        cnt[is.na(cnt)]<-1
        cbind(Sym=y, as.data.frame(xtabs(cnt~ElementSymbol)))
    }, regmatches(x,m), x)
    do.call(rbind, dx)
}
```

Here I test the function

```
test_input <- c("H2O","CH4")
decompose(test_input)

#   Sym ElementSymbol Freq
# 1 H2O             H    2
# 2 H2O             O    1
# 3 CH4             C    1
# 4 CH4             H    4
```

Now we can combine the data and the reference information to make a plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(merge(decompose("CH4"), dd), aes(Column, -Row)) + 
    geom_tile(data=dd, aes(fill=GroupName), color="black") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=Freq))
```

[image]

Clearly there are opportunities for improvement but this should give you a good start.

You might look for a more robust decomposition function. Looks like the `CHNOSZ` package has one

```
library(CHNOSZ)
data(thermo)
decompose <- function(x) {
    do.call(`rbind`, lapply(x, function (x) {
       z <- makeup(x)
       cbind(data.frame(ElementSymbol = names(z),Freq=z), Sym=x)
    }))
}
ggplot(merge(decompose("CaAl2Si2O7(OH)2*H2O"), dd), aes(Column, -Row)) + 
    geom_tile(data=dd, aes(fill=GroupName), color="black") + 
    geom_text(aes(label=Freq))
```

Comment: This is really awesome, I'll post some follow up questions, since I'm liable to use this in many different ways.

Comment: Updated with a more robust decomposing option

Comment: How can I fix the rows so they are discrete and decreasing? I tried using `scale_y_reverse()` and `scale_y_discrete()` but they undid each other.

Comment: Actually, it was easy enough to change Row into an ordered factor.

Comment: FYI, this period table information has a bug. Lutetium and Lawrencium are in the wrong row. But it doesn't matter in principle because I see how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I moved them in the gist data to the bottom section to be consistent with other representations.